# Ant <get>: Download of Ivy.jar suddenly results in PKIX error

Tags: ant, ivy

The download of the Apache Ivy jar inside my Ant script worked for years. Suddenly a `SSLHandshakeException` occurs. Why is that?

Ant script snippet:

```
<target name="download-ivy" unless="offline">

    <mkdir dir="${ivy.jar.dir}"/>
    <!-- download Ivy from web site so that it can be used even without any special installation -->
    <get src="https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.5.0/ivy-2.5.0.jar" 
         dest="${ivy.jar.file}" usetimestamp="true" verbose="true" retries="10"/>
</target>
```

Console output:

```
download-ivy:
      [get] Getting: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.5.0/ivy-2.5.0.jar
      [get] To: C:\Users\mp\.ant\lib\ivy.jar
      [get] local file date : Sun Oct 20 12:39:20 CEST 2019
      [get] Error getting https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/ivy/ivy/2.5.0/ivy-2.5.0.jar to C:\Users\mp\.ant\lib\ivy.jar

BUILD FAILED
ivytargets.xml:18: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1946)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:316)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:310)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1639)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.openConnection(Get.java:731)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.get(Get.java:652)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Get$GetThread.run(Get.java:642)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:397)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1621)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
        ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SSLHandshakeException` is apparently related to the specific JDK 8 version (`jdk8u192-b12`) used in this case.

Using another JDK version (`jdk-8.0.322.6-hotspot`) does not report any problem and succeeds in downloading the Ivy jar.